# How to create a new service using the Google Cloud Run API for node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am working on a node.js project on Google Cloud Platform and I want to start new Cloud Run instances whenever a user wants to start a service. Basically, I want to automatically start a visualization server when the user chooses to visualize their results. That is why I decided to use teh GCP Cloud Run API to create new services when needed. However, the API is very poorly documented and I keep receiving the error:

`Service has no template`

**My question is:** how do I create a new service using the Google Cloud Run client services API?

I tried using the API and I currently wrote the code in this manner:

```
// create a new service
async function callCreateService(){
  // construct request
  
  const request = {
  parent,
  template, 
  serviceId,
  };
  
  // Run request
  const [operation] = await runClient.createService(request);
  const [response] = await operation.promise();
  console.log(`The response is ${response}`);
}


console.log('initiated...');

//callListServices();
callCreateService();
```

I know that the parent is correct because I connected and listed all of the currently running services using the `listServices()` method, but I can't manage to create a new service using `createService()` because I don't know the template's structure and Google Cloud Run's API for node.js is very poorly documented.

Comment: Your design is weird. What creating a service for a user? What's the constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you missed the template for creating cloud run service the following are the arguments for it:

```
const template = {
  spec: {
    container: {
      image: '<your image path>',
    },
    containerPort: 8080,
  },
  scale: {
    replicas: 1,
  },
};

const request = {
  parent: 'projects/my-project',
  serviceId: 'my-service',
  template,
};

const [operation] = await runClient.createService(request);
const [response] = await operation.promise();
console.log(`The response is ${response}`);
```

You can get official documentation for this methods [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/run/latest/run/v2.servicesclient#_google_cloud_run_v2_ServicesClient_createService_member_1_)

If the above did not work you can also pass template related stuff in service in the above doc it is specified empty but you can fill those within spec object as following:

```
const request = {
    parent: 'projects/my-project',
    service: {
      spec: {
        container: {
          image: 'gcr.io/my-project/my-image:latest',
        },
        containerPort: 8080,
      },
      scale: {
        replicas: 1,
      },
    },
    serviceId: '<your_service_id>',
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did it in the end by using the gcloud image, but this worked.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the documentation is poor... but I managed to get it working

I have some service account credentials stored in a json file, locally, that I'm using for the deployment.

```
import { v2 } from '@google-cloud/run';
import fs from 'fs';

const { ServicesClient } = v2;

const sa_data = fs.readFileSync('./sa-key.json', 'utf8');
const sa_json = JSON.parse(sa_data)

const runClient = new ServicesClient({
    credentials: sa_json
});

const project = 'my-project-name'
const location = 'australia-southeast1'

const parent = `projects/${project}/locations/${location}`
const serviceId = 'created-from-node'

const service = {
    template: {
        containers: [
            { image: 'us-docker.pkg.dev/cloudrun/container/hello' }
        ]
    }
}
// Construct request
const request = {
    parent,
    service,
    serviceId,
};

// Run request
const [operation] = await runClient.createService(request);
const [response] = await operation.promise();
```

I basically followed the trail through the node API docs:
Create Service: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/run/latest/google.cloud.run.v2.Services.html#createService1
request object: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/run/latest/google.cloud.run.v2.ICreateServiceRequest.html
service object: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/run/latest/google.cloud.run.v2.IService.html
template object: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/run/latest/google.cloud.run.v2.IRevisionTemplate.html
containers array object: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/run/latest/google.cloud.run.v2.IContainer.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I created a load balancer for the services by using the gcloud image. But this was useful. It's sometimes hard to understand exactly what they mean exactly in the documentation since different sources use different syntax.